# State variable not returning value when the contract is deployed into sepolia test network

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, solc, sepolia

The `manager` state variable captures the value of account that deploys the contract on the network. When deploying the contract on `Ganache` and calling `ContractName.methods.manager().call()`, it returns the value of account that deploys the contract. But when I deploy the same contract using `Metamask` wallet on `Sepolia` test network, fetch the ABI and `console.log` the code `await lottery.methods.manager().call()` it in a different `.js` file, an empty string is returned. Unable to figure out why the function call is returning an empty array.I am using `Solc` compile Solidity and `MOCHA` to write tests.

**CONTRACT**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    //Enter into the lottery by paying more than 0.1 Ether.
    function enter() public payable notManager {
        require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // Random number generator function.
    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return
            uint(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(block.prevrandao , block.timestamp, players)
                )
            );
    }

    //Pick winner from the player pool.
    function pickWinner() public onlyManager {
        require(manager == msg.sender);
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        address payable winner = payable(players[index]);
        uint contractBalance = address(this).balance;
        winner.transfer(contractBalance);
        players = new address[](0); // Reset the player array for a new round
    }

    //Modifier function for only manager.
    modifier onlyManager() {
        require(manager == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    //Modifier function for not being a manager.
    modifier notManager() {
        require(manager != msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    //Returns the players array.
    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory){
    return players;
    }
}
```

Test Code using MOCHA that return the `manager` value correctly.

```
const assert = require("assert");
const { Web3 } = require("Web3");
const ganache = require("ganache");
const { abi, evm } = require("../compile.js");

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

let lottery; //Holds instance of contract.
let accounts; //Holds all accounts provided by ganache test network.
let manager;
let players;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000 }); //Contract deployed by account[0].
  manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();

  players = [];
});

describe("Lottery Contract", () => {
  it("contract deployed", async () => {
    assert.ok(lottery.options.address); //Contract deployed.
  });

  it("address is manager address", async () => {
    // console.log('manager:', manager);
    // console.log('accounts[0]', accounts[0]);
    assert.equal(manager, accounts[0]); //Contract address same as the address of the account that deployed it.
  });

});
```

Code that deployes to Sepolia test network.

```
//to deploy the code on Sepolia Etherum Network.

const config = require("./config.js");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const { Web3 } = require("Web3");
const { abi, evm } = require("./compile.js");

//Creating a provider to sepolia testnet using my account.
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  config.seedPhrase,
  config.sepoliaTestnetUrl
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  try {
    //Get account address from metamask
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
      .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object })
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000,  });

    provider.engine.stop();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
deploy();
```

React Code that fetchs the contract deployed on Sepolia Network and prints on the frontend.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Component } from 'react';
import web3 from './web3.js';
import lottery from './lottery.js';


class App extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {manager: ''};
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
    // console.log(await lottery.options.address)
    console.log(await lottery.methods.manager().call());
    this.setState({manager})
  }


render(){
  return (
    <div> 
      <h2>hi </h2>
      <h2>Lottery Contract</h2>
      <p> This contract is manager by {this.state.manager}</p>
    </div>
    
  );
}

}

export default App;
```

The `lottery.js` module that is called in `App.js` of the react code.

```
import web3 from './web3.js'
const address = '0x33Cd0B5b79df18faDFDDcc3C04316a26170153d4';//Address to which the contract is deployed to.

    const abi = [
        { inputs: [], stateMutability: 'nonpayable', type: 'constructor' },
        {
          inputs: [],
          name: 'enter',
          outputs: [],
          stateMutability: 'payable',
          type: 'function'
        },
        {
          inputs: [],
          name: 'getPlayers',
          outputs: [ [Object] ],
          stateMutability: 'view',
          type: 'function'
        },
        {
          inputs: [],
          name: 'manager',
          outputs: [ [Object] ],
          stateMutability: 'view',
          type: 'function'
        },
        {
          inputs: [],
          name: 'pickWinner',
          outputs: [],
          stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
          type: 'function'
        },
        {
          inputs: [ [Object] ],
          name: 'players',
          outputs: [ [Object] ],
          stateMutability: 'view',
          type: 'function'
        }
      ]
    
      export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `abi` variable in `lottery.js` module. The `abi` should be in JSON format but this is not the case, so the contract object exported could not be read by the web3 library.
Solution: send the abi parameter as a JSON using  `JSON.parse(abi)`.